# Is there finite number of $p$ such $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left\{\frac{k^2}{p}\right\}=\frac{p-3}{2}？$

Tags: summation, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be odd prime number, and $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$,Is there finite number of $p$ such
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left\{\dfrac{k^2}{p}\right\}=\dfrac{p-3}{2}？$$

where $\{x\}=x-[x]$

I known if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$,then we have
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left\{\dfrac{k^2}{p}\right\}=\dfrac{p-1}{2}$can see this 5-th Hong Kong Mathematical Olympiad 2002 [problem and solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h127863p725463)

Answer (score 1):

For $p\ge 7$, this occurs iff the quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ has class number one. This is a consequence of the analytic class number formula. There are only a finite number of such fields. The largest $p$
for which this is true is $p=163$.

Comment: can you  give this reslut some paper or links?Thanks

Comment: @communnites https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533338/sum-of-quadratic-residues/549263

Comment: I can't understand this why 163 is largest ?

Comment: I don't see how the fractional part of $k^2/p$ relates to the Legendre symbol... ?

Comment: This answer seems wrong to me (as I mentioned already in my comments six months ago). The question is about $\left\{\dfrac{k^2}{p}\right\}$ where $\{x\}=x-[x]$, so I don't see any link with quadratic residues or class numbers.