# Conjecture $ \sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\lfloor \frac{i^2}{n}\rfloor \ge \frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)}3$ where $n\in\mathbb N^*$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, summation, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n \in \mathbb {N^*}$ and $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k^2 \bmod n)$$

with the first values 0, 1, 2, 2, 10, 13, 14, 12, 24, 45, 44, 38, 78, 77, 70, 56, 136, 129, 152, 130, 182, 209, 184, 148, 250, 325, 288, 294, 406, 365, 372, 304, 484, 561, 490, 402, 666, 665, 572, 540, 820, 805, 860, 726, 840, 897, 846, 680, 980, 1125

​​and it appears that    $$S_n\leq \frac {n(n-1)}2$$

We can show that $$S_n\leq \frac {n(n-1)}2\iff  \sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor \frac{i^2}{n}\right\rfloor  \ge \frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)}3$$
[we have equality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1332312p7189056) if $n$ is prime and $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$

Do you think this inequality is true?

**Addition :**

We fix a prime number $p$ that satisfies $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $S_n$ be defined as the sum from $k = 0$ to $p^n - 1$ of $(k^2)_{p^n}$. Numerically, it appears that $2S_n = p^n(p^n - p^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$. If we can prove this equality, we can deduce inequality  (the object of the thread) in many cases

Comment: This is sequence $A048153$ in $OEIS$

Comment: The crudest lower bound results in:
$$S_n \geq \dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} - (n-1) = \dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3} - \dfrac{n-1}{2},$$
so I would guess this is possible to do with some more care.

Comment: Related (but maybe kind of sophisticated): search "sum of quadratic residues". E.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533338) gives an exact formula for $n$ a prime of the form $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link

Comment: I also asked the question on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442497/conjecture-sum-i-1n-1-lfloor-fraci2n-rfloor-ge-frac-leftn-1-r

Comment: Your last remark seems to hold more generally (just an observation): If $n=2\prod p_i^{e_i}$ or $n=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ where $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $S_n=\frac{1}{2}n(n-\prod p_i^{\lfloor e_i/2 \rfloor})$.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but I managed to prove that the sum on the question is the same as $$ n(n-1) -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \lceil \sqrt{k \cdot n} \rceil$$. From here, you can prove that this is $\geq \dfrac{n^2}{3}-2n+1$. It seems a little bit off what is wanted.

Comment: @Arthur Queiroz Moura It is proven  for $n=1+4k$  that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left\lfloor \sqrt{in}\right\rfloor =2\left( \frac{n-1} {4}\right) ^{2}-\sum_{x=1}^{\left( n-1\right) /2}\left\lfloor \frac{x^{2} }{n}\right\rfloor $  in this link  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146t416f146h150713_i_12  . So,  I am curious to see how you prove your equality without conditions on n

Comment: @Pascal For each $k \in \{1, \dots n-1 \}$ you count how many $i \in \{1, \dots n-1 \}$ are such that $ \left \lfloor \dfrac{i^2}{n} \right \rfloor = k$. In particular, this is true if and only if 
$$ \left \lfloor \dfrac{i^2}{n} \right \rfloor = k \Longleftrightarrow k \cdot n \leq i^2 < (k+1) \cdot n \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{k \cdot n} \leq i < \sqrt{(k+1) \cdot n}$$
And the number of integers in this interval is $(\lceil \sqrt{(k+1) \cdot n} \rceil - 1)-(\lceil \sqrt{k \cdot n} \rceil) + 1 = \lceil \sqrt{(k+1) \cdot n} \rceil - \lceil \sqrt{k \cdot n} \rceil$. So you sum $k$ times

Comment: You'll get $$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k \cdot (\lceil \sqrt{(k+1) \cdot n} \rceil - \lceil \sqrt{k \cdot n} \rceil) $$ which can be simplified to the desired result

Comment: @ArthurQueirozMoura    Thank you

Comment: Here there is an idea although it doesn't quite work so probably nothing, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients) say that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\{km/n\}=(n-1)/2$ where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part, suppose that with some luck something similar holds for $\sum\{k^2m/n\}\leq(n-1)/2$ so if we set $k=i$ and $m=1$ we get $\sum\{i^2/n\}\leq (n-1)/2$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lfloor i^2/n\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2/n-\sum\{i^2/n\}\geq (n-1)(2n-1)/6-(n-1)/2=(n-1)(2n-1-3)/6=(n-1)(n-2)/3$

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to $S_n \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, where $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k^2 \bmod n)$. The equality holds when $n$ is prime and $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. It appears that the equality $2S_n = p^n(p^n - p^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ when $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Now, that the bounty period is gone, I am posting this ***incomplete*** answer, containing a collection of known results ... nothing new (thus, not deserving any bounty, imo).

---

From [division with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)
$$n\left\lfloor \frac{i^2}{n}\right\rfloor+r_i=i^2, 0\le r_i<n \tag{1}$$
[Then](http://rtybase.blogspot.com/2017/08/the-matter-of-squares-and-rectangles.html)
$$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor \frac{i^2}{n}\right\rfloor=
\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i^2}{n} - \sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{r_i}{n}=
\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}- \sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{r_i}{n} \tag{2}$$

---

**Remark 1.** We have:
$$\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} - \frac{n-1}{2}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3}$$
What is left to show is:
$$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{r_i}{n} \le \frac{n-1}{2}=
\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{n}$$
Or
$$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} r_i \le \sum _{i=1}^{n-1} i \tag{3}$$

---

**Remark 2.** We have $\forall i\le \frac{n}{2}$ $$r_{i}=r_{n-i}$$

[Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences), from:
$$n\left\lfloor \frac{(n-i)^2}{n}\right\rfloor+r_{n-i}=(n-i)^2 \iff\\
n\left\lfloor n-2i+\frac{i^2}{n}\right\rfloor+r_{n-i}=n^2 -2in +i^2\iff\\
n\left\lfloor \frac{i^2}{n}\right\rfloor+r_{n-i}=i^2$$
and the result follows from $(1)$.

---

**Remark 3.** Every $r_i$ is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $n$. One interesting sum is:
$$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \cdot\chi_{n}(i)\tag{4}$$
which "goes over" quadratic residues and non-residues modulo $n$, where
$$\chi_{n}(m)={\begin{cases}\;\;\,0&{\text{ if }}n{\text{ divides }}m\\
+1&{\text{ if }}m\text{ is quadratic residue modulo }n{\text{ and }}n{\text{ does not divide }}m\\
-1&{\text{ if }}m\text{ is not quadratic residue modulo } n{\text{ and }}n{\text{ does not divide }}m\end{cases}}$$
If $n$ ***is a prime***, then $\chi_{n}(m)\equiv\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$ - [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Then, pointing at the [Dirichlet's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Dirichlet%27s_formulas)

- if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then $T(n) < 0$
- if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $T(n) = 0$

---

Now, a summary for the case when $n$ ***is a prime number***, from ***Remark 3***:

- if $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then $$T(n) < 0 \iff
  \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i < \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=-1}^{n-1}i\iff\\
  2\left( \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i\right) < \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i +\sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=-1}^{n-1}i\tag{5a}$$
- if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $$T(n) = 0 \iff
  \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i = \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=-1}^{n-1}i\iff\\
  2\left( \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i\right) = \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i +\sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=-1}^{n-1}i\tag{5b}$$

[However](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus)
$$\sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i +\sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=-1}^{n-1}i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i$$
Also, because $n$ is prime, thus odd, and considering ***Remark 2***
$$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} r_i=2\left( \sum_{i=1 \text{ & }\\ \chi_n(i)=1}^{n-1}i\right)$$

Looking at $5(a)$, $(5b)$ and $(3)$, this proves the result for $n$ - prime.

Comment: Thank you very much